# CSS orientation (landscape|portrait) not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my simple website and I must set custom values for landscape and portrait orientation. But my code is not working. Can you help me?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 769px)  {
  .head-go {
        background-image: url();
        margin-bottom:  8px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 7px;
        z-index: 4996;
   }

  .footer-go {
        height: 3px;
        background-image: url();
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top:  3px;
        z-index: 4995;
   }

  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      .latest-news-form {
        position: fixed;
        width: 45% !important;
        height: 60% !important;
        color: blue;
        margin:  auto;
        border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
        padding:  2px;
        text-align:  center;
        background-color:  #fff;
        z-index: 4997;
      }
 }

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      .latest-news-form {
        position: fixed;
        width: 65% !important;
        margin-right: 270px !important;
        color: red;
        margin:  auto;
        border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
        padding:  2px;
        text-align:  center;
        background-color:  #fff;
        z-index: 4997;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why isn't working. I hope that you help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use media rules without **only** word in `@media only screen` sequence.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 769px)  {
  .head-go {
        background-image: url();
        margin-bottom:  8px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 7px;
        z-index: 4996;
   }

  .footer-go {
        height: 3px;
        background-image: url();
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top:  3px;
        z-index: 4995;
   }

  @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      .latest-news-form {
        position: fixed;
        width: 45% !important;
        height: 60% !important;
        color: blue;
        margin:  auto;
        border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
        padding:  2px;
        text-align:  center;
        background-color:  #fff;
        z-index: 4997;
      }
 }

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      .latest-news-form {
        position: fixed;
        width: 65% !important;
        margin-right: 270px !important;
        color: red;
        margin:  auto;
        border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
        padding:  2px;
        text-align:  center;
        background-color:  #fff;
        z-index: 4997;
    }
  }
}
```